# Background-image e background:linear-gradient

Tags: background, background-image

Estou tentando fazer um background com um efeito curvado, mas para colocar esse efeito eu estou usando uma imagem(link da imagem: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/800754994739150878/800893255343538186/wave.png) mas também quero colocar um efeito gradiente no background, mas quando vou colocar o o gradient junto com o background-image simplesmente não funciona. O que posso fazer?

```html
   <body>
        <section></section>
    </body>
```

```css
   section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: tomato;
    /* background:linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);  */
    background-image:url(../images/wave.png); 
    background-size: 100% 150px;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Radial` e `linear-gradient` são valores de `background-image`, e quando vc usou o CSS assim como abaixo, o `background-image: {}` acabou sobrescrevendo o `gradient` da `background: {}`, isso acontece pq o CSS funciona em cascata.

```
background:linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue); 
background-image:url(../images/wave.png);
```

Para corrigir isso vc tem que usar os dois backgrounds na mesma propriedade, apenas separando eles por vírgula, lembrando que essa técnica serve para todas as propriedades do `background` tipo `bg-position`, `bg-size`, etc. Então seu CSS deveria ser algo assim:

```
background-image:url(../images/wave.png), linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
```

Aqui tem um exemplo didático, repare como foi feito o `BG` do `body`

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/200), linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
  background-size: 200px 200px, cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```